# How to pass Tree struct with CUDA

Tags: tree, cuda, nvidia

I have created a simple C Tree, and I am planning to port it on the GPU.

The structure of my tree is as follow :

```
typedef struct node{

    short int final; // 2 byte
    char number; // 1 byte 
    struct node *child[2]; // 8 * NUM_SIZE byte

}node;
```

I am now wondering how to port the code on CUDA, or how to use structures in CUDA, should I create the tree on the device ? or create the tree on the host and pass it to the device ?

Creating the tree on the device seems to be the best answer to me, although I'm not exactly sure how to use structures on the device.

Thanks

Comment: Using `__host__ __device__` functions and unified memory you can create/modify/traverse pointer-based structure transparently.

Answer (score 7):

There are three basic approaches you could use for this sort of problem:

1. Allocate global memory for the tree using the host APIs and construct the tree on the host, then copy that tree to the device.
2. Allocate global memory for the tree using the host APIs and construct the tree on the device
3. Allocate runtime heap memory for the tree on the device and construct the tree on the device

Which is the most suitable depends a lot on your usage case and what GPU you use. There are disadvantages to each - for example (1) requires holding a copy of the device tree in host memory, (2) may require synchronization which is very difficult to implement in device code, and (3) suffers from the limited performance of device runtime heap memory allocation on those devices which support it, and will produce a tree which cannot be directly accessed using host APIs

A final remark would be that trees based on pointers, in general, are not performant or well suited to GPU computing and you might well want to consider alternative data structures and algorithms before committing to using a structure such as the one you have described in your question.

---

Edit:

Apparently all of these options are proving too difficult for you, so here is an absolutely trivial example you might look at to get some idea of how it is done. First the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct __align__(8) node{
    char val; 
    struct node *child;
};

__global__
void kernel(node * tree, char *out, int n)
{
    node *p = tree;
    int i=0;
    while(p->val != 0) {
    out[i++] = p->val;
    p = p->child;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int n = 15;
    char data[n] = "tietamattomana";
    node tree[n]; 

    node * tree_d;
    char * output_d;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&tree_d, n * sizeof(node));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&output_d, n * sizeof(char));

    node * p = tree_d;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        tree[i].val = data[i];
        tree[i].child = (++p);
    }

    cudaMemcpy(tree_d, tree, n * sizeof(node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(tree_d, output_d, n);

    char output[n];
    cudaMemcpy(output, output_d, n * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::cout << output[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I have just populated a simple linked list on the host and copied it to the device, which each list node holding a value from a host string. A single GPU thread traverves the list from start to end, reading out the value of each node and storing it in an output array. To confirm everything works, the host copies the output array back from the GPU and echoes the contents of the output array, viz:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -Xptxas="-v" tree.cu
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6kernelP4nodePci' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6kernelP4nodePci
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 10 registers, 340 bytes cmem[0]

$ ./a.out 
tietamattomana
```

Perhaps this will at least get you started down the road to whatever it is that you are trying to acheive, and might shed light on how the other possibilities I mentioned might work in practice and where the drawbacks I mentioned will come into play.

Comment: How would you implement the second solution ? do you have any examples of this ? and for the final remark would a tree based on array be a suitable solutions or there would there be something even better?

Comment: @Anoracx: How could I possibly know what solution will be the most suitable for your application when you haven't actually said a single word about what it is you are trying to do here?

Comment: Well, I'm mainly wondering how would you implement both of your proposition, than asking what would be the best, although, I'm looking to implement a simple tree on a GPU, make a few tests and then look on how to implement something like aho corasick (which has already been done in scientific research, I just read some paper about it on google scholar) and see what benefits I have of having it running on GPU.

Comment: @Anoracx: At a minimum, all that is required to build a tree or linked list is a single allocation of memory to hold it (which can be allocated from the host). A kernel running on the device can set values in that memory to build the tree. How practical that is (ie. how much serialization or synchronization is required) is problem specific. You know your problem. I don't.

Comment: well, after multiple tries it's not working, once the memory allocated how do set the values and build the tree? because I can't access my struct.

Comment: @Anoracx: Pardon my ignorance, but what, exactly, isn't working? And what would you like me to do about it?

Comment: Well, I have allocated memory for the tree, on the GPU, I then tried to create the tree, but couldn't populate it, so I was more or less asking if you had an idea on how to do it, since i tried to follow the steps you indicated. So I wonder if you know an example, i could follow.

Comment: @Anoracx: I have edited a really simple example into my answer. It would be good if you would accept this answer just to get the question off the unanswered list.